# execute program in case of grep match

Tags: grep, exec, match, case

Yes I have googled, but i didn't found a solution.

I want to grep a program output and make a date +%s.%N in case of a grep match.
I tried:

```
    cat test.txt | grep test | date +%s.%N
```

but this only calls once how could I do it multiple times?

Answer (score 2):

```
grep test test.txt && date +%s.%N
```

This is a short hand (boolean) for

```
if grep test test.txt; then date +%s.%N; fi
```

**NOTE**

- no need to `cat | grep`, see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat
- if you need to hide grep output you can add `-q` switch to grep (if supported) or do `grep &>/dev/null`
- the `unix` commands have a return status. Based on this, we can use **boolean AND** `&&` or **boolean OR** `||`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to do it on a file.... that was just a test case, I want to grep the output of a running programm...

Comment: The logic is the same : `program | grep test && other_command`

Comment: Hm, no with the the pipe it only starts other_Command once... oh sorry no both start it only once